# Этимология слова "пристальный"

Tags: этимология

Заинтересовало слово "пристальный". Например, если "при-" тут приставка, то корень - "-сталь-"? И от какого же слова тогда оно произошло. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Современный корень - "присталь", исторический - "ста", тот же что и в стоять, стать (с фонетической меной).

*Происходит от прич. прош. присталъ от ~при-стати «пристать, прицепиться», далее от стать; ср.: болг. пристал «усердный». * Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера;